# Parsing serialized PHP data with BNF using Instaparse

Tags: php, parsing, clojure, bnf, ebnf

I have a value serialized by PHP that I need to decode in Clojure.  I'm using this [library](https://gist.github.com/terjesb/5910504) to deserialize it; it uses [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) which utilizes EBNF/ABNF notation to define the grammar.  For reference, here's the full definition:

```
<S> = expr
<expr> = (string | integer | double | boolean | null | array)+
<digit> = #'[0-9]'
<number> = negative* (decimal-num | integer-num)
<negative> = '-'
<integer-num> = digit+
<decimal-num> = integer-num '.' integer-num
<zero-or-one> = '0'|'1'
size = digit+
key = (string | integer)
<val> = expr
array = <'a:'> <size> <':{'> (key val)+ <'}'> <';'>?
boolean = <'b:'> zero-or-one <';'>
null = <'N;'>
integer = <'i:'> number <';'>
double = <'d:'> number <';'>
string = <'s:'> <size> <':\\\"'> #'([^\"]|\\.)*' <'\\\";'>
```

I've found a bug in this library - it can't handle serialized strings that contain the `"` character.

```
php > echo serialize('{"key":"value"}');
s:15:"{"key":"value"}";
```

Deserialized using the library, it blows up when it finds that second `"`:

```
> (deserialize-php "s:15:\"{\"key\":\"value\"}\";")
[:index 7]
```

The problem exists on this line of the grammar definition:

```
string = <'s:'> <size> <':\\\"'> #'([^\"]|\\.)*' <'\\\";'>
```

You'll notice that the string definition excludes the `"` character.  That's not correct though, I could have any character in that string; the size is what matters.  I'm not a BNF expert, so I'm trying to figure out what my options here are.

Is it possible to use the size as the correct number of characters to grab?  If that's not possible, does someone see a way I can tweak the grammar definition to enable correct parsing?

Comment: I'm no expert in BNF, but I haven't seen a definition that defines the number of occurances with another value found in the expression. You'd probably need some backreference like `string = <'s:'> <size> <':\\\"'> ANYCHAR * size <'\\\";'>` - if that isn't possible, you cannot decode the format with BNF. You should probably use a more generic format like JSON if you can.

Comment: I wish I could use JSON.  This app needs to work in parallel and share sessions with a PHP app during transition, and PHP's session data is stored serialized.  Other options like overhauling the PHP app's session management or delegating the decoding to PHP have their own mountains to scale.

Comment: Well, the PHP side should be pretty easy to change. You can define custom session handler functions, and you can store the data in JSON format. But you have to make sure that you apply proper locking, otherwise things will break. This also applies to the replacement code that also needs to lock the files - and do so with a mechanism compatible with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stated by Arthur Ulfeldt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520364/1756702), this grammar is [not context-free due to the bencoded strings](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9645/can-bencodes-be-described-with-a-context-free-grammar/9663#9663). Nonetheless, it is a simple one to parse, just not with A/EBNF. For example, using *[Parse-EZ](https://github.com/protoflex/parse-ez)* instead:

A convenience macro:

```
(defmacro tagged-sphp-expr [tag parser] 
  `(fn [] (between #(string ~(str tag ":")) #(~parser) #(string ";"))))
```

The rest:

```
(def sphp-integer (tagged-sphp-expr "i" integer))

(def sphp-decimal (tagged-sphp-expr "d" decimal))

(defn sphp-boolean [] 
  (= \1 ((tagged-sphp-expr "b" #(chr-in "01")))))

(defn sphp-null [] (string "N;") :null)

(defn sphp-string []
  (let [tag (string "s:")
        size (integer)
        open (no-trim #(string ":\""))
        contents (read-n size)
        close (string "\";")]
    contents))

(declare sphp-array)

(defn sphp-expr [] 
  (any #(sphp-integer) #(sphp-decimal) #(sphp-boolean) #(sphp-null) #(sphp-string) #(sphp-array)))

(defn sphp-key [] 
  (any #(sphp-string) #(sphp-integer)))

(defn sphp-kv-pair [] 
  (apply array-map (series #(sphp-key) #(sphp-expr))))

(defn sphp-array []
  (let [size (between #(string "a:") #(integer) #(string ":{"))
        contents (times size sphp-kv-pair)] 
    (chr \})
    (attempt #(chr \;))
    contents))
```

The test:

```
(def test-str "i:1;d:2;s:16:\"{\"key\": \"value\"}\";a:2:{s:3:\"php\";s:3:\"sux\";s:3:\"clj\";s:3:\"rox\";};b:1;")

(println test-str)
;=> i:1;d:2;s:16:"{"key": "value"}";a:2:{s:3:"php";s:3:"sux";s:3:"clj";s:3:"rox";};b:1;

(parse #(multi* sphp-expr) test-str)
;=> [1 2.0 "{\"key\": \"value\"}" [{"php" "sux"} {"clj" "rox"}] true]
```

Comment: States why it is impossible to use BNF for this and offers a viable solution; thanks a lot!  This should get cleaned up into a proper library someday.

Comment: The test doesn't include null, which in my PHP is serialized as "N;" and not as "N:;". Furthermore, I get a parse error when I fix this and include a null. Seems as if sphp-null is not allowed to return nil. If I change from nil to e.g. :NULL it works. Can a Parse-EZ function parse something as nil?

Comment: @terjesb Thanks for the corrections. Based on your comment, I suspect Parse-EZ is using `nil` as a failure, but I haven't looked into it. Returning `:null` makes sense and you could [walk](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html) the result to replace with `nil` if desired.

Answer (score 2):

I reasonably sure you can't write that with just a EBNF parser because as far as I understand it this grammar is not context-free.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you could come in a context-free grammar is to explicitly enumerate all of the expected length prefixes - something along the lines of the ABNF:

```
 string = 's:0:"";' /
          's:1:"' CHAR '";' /
          's:2:"' 2CHAR '";' /
          's:3:"' 3CHAR '";' / ...
```

This might work reasonably well if the length of your strings is bounded, but obviously won't work for an arbitrarily-sized strings.

Otherwise, to correctly handle arbitrary-length strings, your best option is probably to parse by hand. Fortunately for a grammar of this size, that shouldn't be too difficult a task.